# My ssh server is down. Now what?

Tags: linux, ssh

I believe I did something stupid here... Can you help me out?
I just updated the config of my ssh server (changed the port). So I decided to restart the server: `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`.

Maybe there was a better idea, but what's done is done.
Now here's the thing: apparently it didn't restart. I can't reach it, and I was the only guy with access to this server. Good thing: nothing critical is run on it.

But is there a way I can recover from such failure, or am I in for a full reinstall ?

Comment: Do you have access through other means, an OOB (out-of-band) console, like Dell's DRAC, HP's iLO, other...?

Comment: I'm guessing that you neglected to update the firewall configuration too.

Comment: Is there a chance SSH is running but a firewall is blocking your access to the new port?

Comment: Hmm... Good point... Now that you mention it, I seem to remember iptables rules that forbid port 22 :(

Comment: Even an ssh restart usually keeps the current server process running. So you should always test using a second window of your ssh client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you know that it failed to restart ?

Did you see any error messages somewhere or you are just guessing because you are not able to connect ?

My best educated guess is that, the ssh didn't fail to restart. It's just that you forgot to update the firewall to allow the traffic for that specific port to which you changed the SSH configs.
That is what is blocking you from accessing that machine.

Simple update your firewall rules and it should be fine.

Thanx

Answer (score 6):

Connect to it via the console instead of SSH and fix your SSH configuration.

Comment: Can't do: it's a remote remote server. No physical access.

Comment: Live and learn...

Comment: No lights out management (ILO, DRAC, etc)? No KVM-over-IP? You should never have a server that you can't physically get to without lights out management.

Comment: @mdmarra People who buy VPS and other hosted servers typically don't have [out-of-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) server access.

Comment: @ewwhite Linode provides OOB access to the "real" console, which is one of the reasons I choose them over many other providers.

Comment: @ewwhite agree, will learn :)

Comment: Ask your hoster to fix it for you, and pay the price of learning on a machine that is not designed to be a lab.

Comment: Quite a few VPS hosts provide a web based fallback console - specifically for this sort of oopsie.